# sub_filter replace text within some other text

Tags: regex, nginx

How can I replace `xxx` between `abc` and `yyy` using sub_filter module?
`...other_text abc def ghi jkl xxx yyy abc`

the following regex doesn't match:
`sub_filter (?:\G(?!\A)|abc)(?:(?!abc).)*?\Kxxx(?=(?:(?!abc).)*?yyy) REPLACED_TEXT;`

Comment: `ngx_http_sub_module` doesn't have a regex support. You can try `nginx_substitutions_filter` module: [nginx wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/), [github](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module).

Comment: @IvanShatsky thank you I didn't know sub_filter doesn't support regex. I've recompiled nginx again with this module. it works now!

Comment: Moss, please add your solution as an answer. Add exact steps you followed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan.
I've solved this using `nginx_substitutions_filter` by recompiling nginx with the following option:
`--add-module=/opt/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module`